# Extracting text context associated with a tag in python

Tags: python, parsing, text

Let's say I have the following text:

> Lorem ipsum <ID-A01> dolor </ID-A01> sit <ID-A02> amet </ID-A02>,
> consectetur adipiscing elit. In id mauris fringilla, auctor odio
> mattis, finibus ligula. Aliquam urna <ID-A01> dolor </ID-A01>,
> viverra non ligula a, pellentesque sagittis tempor.

I want to retrieve the context associated with every tag in a custom window, for example `get_context(text, window=4)` would return something like:

```
{
    'A01': [['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'],['Aliquam', 'urna', 'dolor', ',', 'viverra']],
    'A02': [['dolor', 'sit', 'amet', ',', 'consectetur']]
}
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: It would help if you could simplify the example to make it more clear how you transformed the input text to the requirement. It is not clear if every tag is associated with the words that exists prior to or after that tag. Not clear what the implication of the commas and periods in the input text will be. Are you treating those as normal text. What makes you split the dictionary value into two list elements?

Comment: For example - how exactly is `Lorem` "associated" with `AO1`?